# IllegalAccessException in Android Studio where target android is 4.4

Tags: java, android

In my android project, I had originally targeted Android 6 and it all ran OK.

Now I'm running it on a Android 4.4 device (both a real device and an AVD) it crashes with an IllegalAccessException.

This is where it's crashing

```
    this.PractitionerList.add(new
            PractitionerItem(1, "01A1234E", "Mary", "1st", "London", "Y")

    );
```

PractitionerItem is a public class and PractitionerList is an arraylist declared like this

this.PractitionerList = new ArrayList();

This is the logcat....

---

> 08-08 02:47:05.491 2637-2637/org.nmc_uk.www.thenmc I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful
>   08-08 02:47:05.561 2637-2637/org.nmc_uk.www.thenmc W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable > to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
>   08-08 02:47:05.561 2637-2637/org.nmc_uk.www.thenmc I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
>   08-08 02:47:05.561 2637-2637/org.nmc_uk.www.thenmc W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 19611: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
>   08-08 02:47:05.561 2637-2637/org.nmc_uk.www.thenmc D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
>   08-08 02:47:05.571 2637-2637/org.nmc_uk.www.thenmc I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
>   08-08 02:47:05.571 2637-2637/org.nmc_uk.www.thenmc W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 19615: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
>   08-08 02:47:05.571 2637-2637/org.nmc_uk.www.thenmc D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
>   08-08 02:47:05.891 2637-2637/org.nmc_uk.www.thenmc I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
>   08-08 02:47:05.891 2637-2637/org.nmc_uk.www.thenmc W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 649: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
>   08-08 02:47:05.891 2637-2637/org.nmc_uk.www.thenmc D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
>   08-08 02:47:05.891 2637-2637/org.nmc_uk.www.thenmc I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
>   08-08 02:47:05.891 2637-2637/org.nmc_uk.www.thenmc W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 671: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
>   08-08 02:47:05.911 2637-2637/org.nmc_uk.www.thenmc D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
>   08-08 02:47:06.071 2637-2637/org.nmc_uk.www.thenmc D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 141K, 7% free 2923K/3112K, paused 51ms, total 51ms
>   08-08 02:47:06.071 2637-2637/org.nmc_uk.www.thenmc I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 3.502MB for 635808-byte allocation
>   08-08 02:47:06.091 2637-2646/org.nmc_uk.www.thenmc D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 6% free 3542K/3736K, paused 16ms, total 16ms[ 08-08 02:47:06.301  2637: 2637 D/         ]HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb903efa0, tid 2637
>   08-08 02:47:06.421 2637-2637/org.nmc_uk.www.thenmc D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
>   08-08 02:47:13.121 2637-2637/org.nmc_uk.www.thenmc I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable
>   08-08 02:47:13.121 2637-2637/org.nmc_uk.www.thenmc W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 612: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
>   08-08 02:47:13.121 2637-2637/org.nmc_uk.www.thenmc D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
>   08-08 02:47:13.121 2637-2637/org.nmc_uk.www.thenmc I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawableForDensity
>   08-08 02:47:13.121 2637-2637/org.nmc_uk.www.thenmc W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 614: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
>   08-08 02:47:13.121 2637-2637/org.nmc_uk.www.thenmc D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
>   08-08 02:47:13.161 2637-2637/org.nmc_uk.www.thenmc D/---:: listView.setOnItemClickListener
>   08-08 02:47:15.021 2637-2637/org.nmc_uk.www.thenmc I/Choreographer: Skipped 110 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>   08-08 02:47:16.841 2637-2637/org.nmc_uk.www.thenmc D/---:: Inserting ..
>   08-08 02:47:16.841 2637-2637/org.nmc_uk.www.thenmc E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'org.nmc_uk.www.thenmc.PractitionerItem$1', referenced from method org.nmc_uk.www.thenmc.PractitionerItem.
>   08-08 02:47:16.841 2637-2637/org.nmc_uk.www.thenmc W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 9673 (Lorg/nmc_uk/www/thenmc/PractitionerItem$1;) in Lorg/nmc_uk/www/thenmc/PractitionerItem;
>   08-08 02:47:16.841 2637-2637/org.nmc_uk.www.thenmc D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0000
>   08-08 02:47:16.841 2637-2637/org.nmc_uk.www.thenmc D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0xfe57 at 0x02 in Lorg/nmc_uk/www/thenmc/PractitionerItem;.
>   08-08 02:47:16.901 2637-2637/org.nmc_uk.www.thenmc W/dalvikvm: Exception Ljava/lang/NoClassDefFoundError; thrown while initializing Lorg/nmc_uk/www/thenmc/PractitionerItem;
>   08-08 02:47:16.901 2637-2637/org.nmc_uk.www.thenmc D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
>   08-08 02:47:16.901 2637-2637/org.nmc_uk.www.thenmc W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2d53b20)
>   08-08 02:47:18.551 2637-2637/org.nmc_uk.www.thenmc E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   Process: org.nmc_uk.www.thenmc, PID: 2637
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
>
> ### at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:275) at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)

This is the class....

```
package org.nmc_uk.www.xxxxx;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class PractitionerItem implements Parcelable {
Integer PRN;
String PIN;
String Fname;
String Lname;
String Town;
String YesNo;



@Override
public int describeContents() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel (Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeInt(PRN);
    dest.writeString(PIN);
    dest.writeString(Fname);
    dest.writeString(Lname);
    dest.writeString(Town);
    dest.writeString(YesNo);
}

private PractitionerItem(Parcel in){
    this.PRN = in.readInt();
    this.PIN = in.readString();
    this.Fname = in.readString();
    this.Lname = in.readString();
    this.Town = in.readString();
    this.YesNo = in.readString();
}

public static final Creator<PractitionerItem> CREATOR = new Creator<PractitionerItem>() {

    @Override
    public PractitionerItem createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        return new PractitionerItem(source);
    }

    @Override
    public PractitionerItem[] newArray(int size) {
        return new PractitionerItem[size];
    }
};
public PractitionerItem(Integer PRN, String PIN, String Fname, String Lname, String Town, String YesNo){
    this.PRN = PRN;
    this.PIN = PIN;
    this.Fname = Fname;
    this.Lname = Lname;
    this.Town = Town;
    this.YesNo = YesNo;
}
```

}

..... and this (the main bits) from the class that calls it...

---

```
Public class SearchTheRegister extends AppCompatActivity {

private ArrayList<PractitionerItem> PractitionerList;

private CustomAdapter practitioner_adapter;
.
.
.

 //// THIS LINE IS WHERE IT FAILS /////////////// 
    this.PractitionerList.add(new
            PractitionerItem(1, "01A1234E", "Mary", "1st", "London", "Y")

    );
```

Any ideas?

Sam

Comment: Post the whole logcat of the crash.

Comment: full code + logcat will help others feel it easy to figure out what the problem is

Comment: do you init your list in your application? and when you run app it suddenly gets crash?

Comment: Hi,To answer your 2nd question 1st, it only crashes at this line. everything else runs fine.  

I recoded the failing line like this


           PractitionerItem pract = new PractitionerItem(1, "01A1234E", "Mary", "1st", "London", "Y")

Comment: Hi,To answer your 2nd question 1st, it only crashes at this line. everything else runs fine.  

I recoded the failing line like this
.
.
           PractitionerItem pract = new PractitionerItem(1, "01A1234E", "Mary", "1st", "London", "Y")
.
and it fails at tat line, so it's not related to the list not being initialised.
.
As I said it works fine when I target api version 23. It only fails when it targets api version 19.
.
So is there anything different about these two versions in the way you code parcelable classes?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this'll fix your problem but i have similar issue and i realised my parcelable implementation is wrong. I re generated a parcelable implementation for you below:

```
    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeValue(this.PRN);
        dest.writeString(this.PIN);
        dest.writeString(this.Fname);
        dest.writeString(this.Lname);
        dest.writeString(this.Town);
        dest.writeString(this.YesNo);
    }

    public PractitionerItem() {
    }

    protected PractitionerItem(Parcel in) {
        this.PRN = (Integer) in.readValue(Integer.class.getClassLoader());
        this.PIN = in.readString();
        this.Fname = in.readString();
        this.Lname = in.readString();
        this.Town = in.readString();
        this.YesNo = in.readString();
    }

    public static final Creator<PractitionerItem> CREATOR = new Creator<PractitionerItem>() {
        @Override
        public PractitionerItem createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new PractitionerItem(source);
        }

        @Override
        public PractitionerItem[] newArray(int size) {
            return new PractitionerItem[size];
        }
    };
```

If this won't work you can try to add `MultiDex` support to your app. There is a strange issue about `Kitkat`, `ArrayList` and Parcelable.

To add multidex support:

First change your gradle like below:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        multiDexEnabled true
        ...
    }
}

dependencies {
  ...
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
  ...
```

}

Second extend your Application from Multidex Application or call `Multidex.init` in `OnCreate`:

```
public class YourApplication extends MultiDexApplication
{
    ...
}
```

or

```
public class YourApplication extends Application
{
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base)
    {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
}
```

If these solutions don't work please let me know and let us try to figure out a new fix.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. . . . .    I've done both of those but it still crashes. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can try making Integer primitive.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by this. In my class where I've defined any (integer) variables they are primitive...., or have I completely missed your point?

Comment: Your PRN property is Integer, not 'int'. Not sure but it worths a try.